# target page with php based on page slug

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets say I have six pages in wordpress

```
example.com/apples
example.com/art
example.com/bananas
example.com/broccoli
example.com/cars
example.com/cats
```

I want to target pages which slugs begin with specific letter

```
if (page slug beginns with "a"){
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with a';
}
else if (page slug beginns with "b"){
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with b';
}
else if (page slug beginns with "c"){
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with c';
}
```

How do I write this correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188945/104023), I'd say it's safe to get the URL like this:

```
/** Get the queried object and sanitize it */
$current_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );

/** Get the page slug */
$slug = $current_page->post_name;
```

And then:

```
/** Get the first character */
$slugBeginsWith = substr($slug, 0, 1);

/** Apply your logic */
if($slugBeginsWith == 'a')
{
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with a';
}
elseif($slugBeginsWith == 'b')
{
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with b';
}
elseif($slugBeginsWith == 'c')
{
    echo 'content for pages with slug beginning with c';
}
```

However you didn't mention what is your goal here. Maybe if you provide more information in your question we could help better!

Answer (score 1):

you need to get the firstcharacter by using php [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. place following code in functions.php file

```
add_filter('the_content', 'change_content_by_firstCharacter');  

function change_content_by_firstCharacter( $content ) {

global $post;
$post_slug = $post->post_name;
$firstCharacter = substr($post_slug, 0, 1);


if ( $firstCharacter == 'a' ) {
  $content = 'content for a goes here';
 } else {
    return $content;
 }
}
```